# How can I force a Loop/Link to use Index.php instead of Single.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some links in my home page that i want to force them to open in the index.php instead of single.php.

Is that possible ?

```
<div id="RightBar">
<?php query_posts('category_name=new_publish&showposts=100'); ?> <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <a class="Publish_Num" href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?> ">
        <?php echo rwmb_meta( '_mb_monthly_number'); ?>
    </a>
<?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to force them to open?".

Answer (score 0):

**If you just mean to redirect a single page with id = `$postid`  to index page then this would do : -**

```
function redirect_postid_to_index() {   
     if(is_single('$postid')){

        header(bloginfo('url'));
        exit;

        }
    }

    add_action('init','redirect_postid_to_index');
```

Comment: there is not constant number of post that i want to redirect to index page. it will be increase because its number of published monthly. so after a month, i'll have a new post that i want redirect to index.php.

Comment: then you can make a template for that and you can assign that template to each of your posts. that template would contain redirect code .